# Rails one-to-many and forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im starting off with Rails and was trying to implement a basic Q & A website.
One question has many answers.

How do I create a new question that attaches to an existing answer?

All the available tutorials on the web are for nested forms, which is not what im looking for. The question already exists. I just want to attach new answers to it.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do this so.

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

Routes:

```
resources :questions do
  resources :answers
end
```

Here:   /questions/1/answers/new
Controller: Answer
Action: new

return an HTML form for creating a new ad belonging to a specific question

POST    /questions/1/answers
create  create a new ad belonging to a specific question

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

https://github.com/rusak1 - send a letter for me here

Comment: change 'belongs_to :questions' to  'belongs_to :question'